# How to resume flow after exception

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have the following code:

```
val channel = BroadcastChannel<Event>(10)

fun setup() {
    scope.launch {
        channel.asFlow().
            .flatMapLatest { fetchSomeData() }
            .catch { emit(DefaultData()) }
            .onEach { handleData() }
            .collect()

    }
}

fun load() {
    channel.offer(Event.Load)      
}
```

In case `fetchSomeData` fails with an exception it will be caught by `catch` and some default data is passed on. The problem is that the flow itself gets canceled and is being removed from the subscribers of the channel. This means that any new events offered to the channel will be ignored since there are no longer any subscribers.

Is there a way to make sure the flow does not get cancelled in case of an exception?

Comment: It should at least be possible to ensure no exceptions escape from operators by using a plain `try-catch` block within them. However, when I tried it, i hit a Kotlin compiler bug.

Comment: Exceptions don't really escape in this case. That is not the problem.

Comment: Exceptions do escape the operator, cancelling the flow. If you didn't let them escape the operator and handled them locally, then the flow would not get cancelled.

Comment: Okay. Now I understand what you mean. Let's just assume that this is out of our control and `fetchSomeData` just returns a flow. I am looking for an approach similar to RxJava.

Comment: probably you need `fetchSomeData().catch { emit(DefaultData()) }` instead?

Comment: @gookman Did you have a progress on this?

Comment: @jzarsuelo check the accepted answer.

Comment: @gookman Thanks! That one worked though I don't get why do the catch is necessary in `fetchSomeData()`, I'm thought the `catch()` after `flatMapLatest` is enough.

Comment: I believe it's because `fetchSomeData` in `flatMapLatest` is running in a child coroutine scope. If the exception is being caught in the child scope, then it is handled there and not passed on to the parent scope.  This is my understanding from skimming `kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.Merge.kt`.

Comment: Thanks! I should also check that part. I didn't expect the behaviour of the exception handling will be like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should catch exception of fetchSomeData(), so move `catch` from main flow to fetchSomeData():

```
    scope.launch {
        channel.asFlow().
            .flatMapLatest { fetchSomeData().catch { emit(DefaultData()} }
            .onEach { handleData() }
            .collect()

    }
```

Comment: Extra information here: for this to work the exception needs to be thrown in the flow returned by `fetchSomeData`. If `fetchSomeData` itself returns an exception it will not be caught.

Comment: @gildor how does catching the exception in `fetchSomeData()` worked? I thought it cascade any exception to the main flow.

Comment: @jzarsuelo fetchSomeData returns flow, and by adding catch on it, every fail of this flow will be replaced with DefaultData(), so failed even will not be propagated to parent flow

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same issue. My workaround is something like this:

```
/* Custom onEach extension function */
fun <T> Flow<T>.onEachCatching(block: suspend (T) -> Unit) = OnEachCatching(this, block)

class OnEachCatching<T>(private val src: Flow<T>, private val block: suspend (T) -> Unit, bufferCapacity: Int = Channel.CONFLATED) {

    private val okValue = Channel<T>(bufferCapacity)

    private var failBlock: (suspend (Throwable) -> Unit)? = null

    init {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            src.collect { value ->
                runCatching { block(value) }
                    .onFailure { failBlock?.invoke(it) }
                    .onSuccess { okValue.send(value) }
            }

            okValue.close()
        }
    }

    fun onFailure(block: suspend (Throwable) -> Unit) = this.also {
        failBlock = block
    }

    fun resumeFlow() = okValue.consumeAsFlow()
}
```

Usage:

```
someData
    .onEachCatching { handleData() }
    .onFailure { emit(DefaultData()) }
    .resumeFlow()
    .collect()
```

Answer (score -3):

My desigion is to simply restart collect flow

```
private fun startParsingMessages() {
    coroutineScope?.launch {
        sessionController.subscribeToMessages()
            .onEach { /*code block*/ }
            .catch {
                it.cause
                    ?.let { error -> Timber.e(error) }
                    ?: Timber.e("startSession(): ${it.message}")

                startParsingMessages() //here
            }
            .collect()
    }
}
```