# How to suppress Error in a Coroutine Flow, so the Flow doesn't complete?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow, kotlin-coroutines

I have a flow which could possible throw an error like so:

```
val myFlow = flow {
    emit("1")
    delay(2000)
    emit("2")
    delay(2000)
    emit("3")
    delay(2000)
    emit("4")
    delay(2000)
    throw Exception() // here it would throw an error
    delay(10000)
    emit("6")  // because the flow completes on error, it doesn't emit this
}
```

My problem is that, when the error is thrown even when I add a `.catch { error -> emit("5") }`.. it still completes the flow, and so `"6"` isnt emitted.

```
myFlow.catch { error ->
    emit("5")
}.onEach {
    println("$it")
}.onCompletion {
    println("Complete")
}.launchIn(scope)
```

And the result is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
Complete
```

I need it to be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
Complete
```

I want to swallow the error instead of making the flow complete. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `try { throw Exception() } catch(e: Exception) { emit("5") }`

Comment: Could you explain your use-case about what you want to achieve? So that proper solution can be provided

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63989251/3736955

Answer (score 5):

OK, I know it's not exactly the same example but I suspect my case is somewhat similar.

Let`s say you have some kind of risky flow. The flow may throw an exception. But you want to maintain the connection with the flow even after exception, because it emits some important, e.g., server real-time updates.

And your goal is suppress an exception or convert it to some data and continue listening to the real-time updates no matter what.

```
    var counter = 0

    val riskyFlow = flow {

        while (true) {
            counter++

            delay(1000)

            if (counter == 3) 
                throw IllegalStateException("Oops! Error.")
            else 
                emit("Server update")
            
        }
    }
```

If you use **catch**, risky-flow will complete after you emit something you want on error.

```
riskyFlow
        .catch { cause -> emit("Emit on error") }
        .onEach { println(it) }
        .launchIn(GlobalScope)
```

**Solution**

Use `retry` or `retryWhen`. This way you suppress exception by emitting some data on exception, then you'll restart the connection to the flow right away, so it'll continue emitting its data.

```
riskyFlow
        .retryWhen { cause, attempt ->
            emit("emit on error")
            true
        }
        .onEach { println(it) }
        .launchIn(GlobalScope)
```

The output is:

```
I/System.out: Server update
I/System.out: Server update
I/System.out: emit on error
I/System.out: Server update
I/System.out: Server update
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in your current example since the last 2 lines in your flow are unreachable.

you should deal with the exception inside of your flow meaning catch the exception in the flow and emit 5 in your example.

Like this

```
val myFlow = flow {
        emit("1")
        delay(2000)
        emit("2")
        delay(2000)
        emit("3")
        delay(2000)
        emit("4")
        delay(2000)
        try {
            throw Exception() // here it would throw an error
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            emit("5")
        }
        delay(10000)
        emit("6")  // because the flow completes on error, it doesn't emit this
    }
```

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones cold flows follow standard execution logic. Your question is equivalent to "how to continue to execute body of a method after exception is thrown". This is not possible because exception throwing breaks the execution, that's how JVM works.

Comment: This is wrong. Since exception is catched in flow, flow does not complete and "6" is emitted.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered same problem today, with some extension functions magic here is my solution:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        flow {
            for (i in 0..10) {
                emit(i)
            }
        }
            .allowErrors()
            .onEachSuccess {
                if (it == 3 || it == 6) {
                    throw RuntimeException("$it !!!")
                }
            }
            .mapSuccess { "Success :$it; " }
            .onEachError {
                println("ERROR: ${it.message}")
            }
            .reduceSuccess { a, b -> a + b }
            .also { println(it) }
    }   
}

fun <T> Flow<T>.allowErrors(): Flow<Pair<T?, Throwable?>> = transform { value ->
    return@transform emit(value to null)
}

fun <T> Flow<Pair<T?, Throwable?>>.filterSuccess(predicate: suspend (T) -> Boolean): Flow<Pair<T?, Throwable?>> =
    transform { value ->
        if (value.second == null) {
            try {
                if (predicate(value.first!!)) return@transform emit(value)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                emit(value.first to e)
            }
        } else {
            return@transform emit(value)
        }
    }


fun <T> Flow<Pair<T?, Throwable?>>.onEachSuccess(action: suspend (T) -> Unit): Flow<Pair<T?, Throwable?>> =
    transform { value ->
        if (value.second == null) {
            try {
                action(value.first!!)
                return@transform emit(value)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                emit(value.first to e)
            }
        } else {
            return@transform emit(value)
        }
    }

fun <T, R> Flow<Pair<T?, Throwable?>>.mapSuccess(transform: suspend (T) -> R): Flow<Pair<R?, Throwable?>> =
    transform { value ->
        if (value.second == null) {
            try {
                return@transform emit(transform(value.first!!) to null)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                emit(null to e)
            }
        } else {
            return@transform emit(null to value.second)
        }
    }

fun <T> Flow<Pair<T?, Throwable?>>.onEachError(action: suspend (Throwable) -> Unit): Flow<Pair<T?, Throwable?>> =
    transform { value ->
        if (value.second != null) {
            action(value.second!!)
            return@transform emit(value)
        } else {
            return@transform emit(value)
        }
    }

suspend fun <T> Flow<Pair<T?, Throwable?>>.collectSuccess(collector: FlowCollector<T>) {
    this@collectSuccess.filter { it.second == null }.map { it.first!! }.collect(collector)
}

suspend fun <S, T : S> Flow<Pair<T?, Throwable?>>.reduceSuccess(operation: suspend (accumulator: S, value: T) -> S): S {
    return this@reduceSuccess.filter { it.second == null }.map { it.first!! }.reduce(operation)
}
```

https://pl.kotl.in/HOpFfv6Hc